# Oracle Apex : How to execute procedure and display the results on a page

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a procedure that dynamically takes application id as input and displays the result as per application id.

So if :

```
exec get_app_data(11);
```

Result would be:

```
A   B   C

1   2   3
1   2   3
```

And if:

```
exec get_app_data(12);

D   E   F

1   2   3
1   2   3
```

So basically it caters the requirement of dynamically changing column headers and displaying dynamic views.

Now how do i add this procedure to oracle apex page?
I understand it would be first added as a page process for execution, but how do i display the results also since the results are dynamic and at runtime?

EDIT: For further clarity this is the procedure which is being executed:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a region of type Classic Report, where its source is based on a PL/SQL Function Body Returning SQL Query.

You would then simplify your code by removing the cursor stuff and have the parameter be based on a page item. Perhaps something like this:

```sql
declare
    l_query varchar2(4000);
begin
    SELECT 'SELECT  *' || CHR(10) ||
           '  FROM  DATA_VALUE' || CHR(10) ||
           '  PIVOT(' || CHR(10) ||
           '        MAX(VAL)' || CHR(10) ||
           '        FOR SEQ IN (' || CHR(10) ||
           '                    ' || LISTAGG(
                                             SEQ || ' "' || LABEL || '"',
                                             ',' || CHR(10) ||'                    '
                                            )
                                     WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SEQ) || CHR(10) ||
           '                   )' || CHR(10) ||
           '       )' || CHR(10) ||
           '  WHERE APP_ID = ' || APP_ID
      INTO l_query
      FROM DATA_HEADER
     WHERE APP_ID = :P1_APP_ID
     GROUP BY APP_ID;

    return l_query;
end;
```

Comment: I tried and it is throwing error when i save it in source: no data found

Comment: 1) Make sure the page item is populated properly. If it's null, you would probably get this error.
2) Try running the page in debug LEVEL9, then check the logs. You should see the final query that's being run by APEX. Maybe it helps pin point the error.